# Can jQuery bind to an iframe's onload event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, onload

I know that jQuery can’t bind to a file input’s `onchange` event. Is it also the case that it can’t bind to an inframe’s `onload` event?

With this HTML,

```
<iframe src="http://jsfiddle.net" onload="alert('js alert');"></iframe>
```

and this javascript,

```
$("iframe").live("onload",function(){alert('jq alert');});
```

I get the alert `js alert`, not `jq alert`, so jQuery is not binding to the `onload` event.

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhapsodyn/mk5VE/2/).

I can’t understand why jQuery cannot bind to the `onload` event in time (as [ThiefMaster said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7900132)). Is `onload` so different from other events?

Comment: @AwaisQarni. I've rewritten the question. Does it make more sense to you now?

Answer (score 3):

The event has already fired at the point where you register the event handler. If you need to handle the onload event and want to avoid ugly inline event handlers, create the iframe through jQuery and attach the event handler before setting the url or attaching it to the document.

Comment: it is possible, look at my answer

Comment: I cant understand why the jquery cant bind the onload event in time. Onload is that different from other events?

Comment: can u show me a "create the iframe through jQuery and attach the event handler before setting the url or attaching it to the document" example??

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you can't catch the `onload` event because the event already fired and flew away at that time.

Here is a solution to catch the event:

#### HTML

```
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("iframe").load(function() { alert('load complete'); });
  $("iframe").error(function() { alert('error occurs'); });
  $("iframe").attr("src", "http://google.com");
});
```

When you provide the `src`, the load/error event fired. So, before provide `src`, bind events you want to handle.

You can also use this trick to `<img>`!